# running mysql in a kubernetes init container

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am running mysql as an init container for a kubernetes deployment.

For various reasons i need to spin up mysql in a init container/restore a mysql dump -> save it to a pvc and then the main pod will be a mysql pod with the data attached.

This is because i need to take a snapshot of the disk and im going to have CI watch for the pod to be "ready/running" before i take the snapshot.

So i cant just dump the dump.sql in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and be done with it.

This is because the volumesnapshot kubernetes resources would be taken before the data is restored/ready.  Hence why i need the data to be prepared in an init container.

The problem i am having is an init container needs a command which overwrites the entrypoint.sh (which actually starts mysql ect)

So far i have this bash script which is run on the container startup.

```
./entrypoint.sh --ignore-db-dir=lost+found 
echo "done" (this is just purely for testing purposes to see if it ever gets processed and it doesnt)
mysql -u root -ppassword < /data/backups/backup.sql
mysql -u root -ppassword < /sql-files/sql-files.sql
```

the problem is, the entrypoint is run but then just hangs with

```
2022-01-14T15:07:54.809983Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-01-14T15:07:54.810442Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.36'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

and never moves onto the next step of the bash script. i've tried adding a & to the end so it is run in the background and this doesn't solve the problem.

has anyone ever come across this issue?  How can i manually run the entrypoint and then execute some commands after.

Ive also tried this, which should run it in the background and exit, but it still doesnt.

```
#!/bin/sh

start_mysql () {
    sleep 30
    #mysql -u root -ppassword < /data/backups/backup.sql
    #mysql -u root -ppassword < /sql-files/sql-files.sql
    echo "hi"
    sleep 30
    echo "done 123354543543" >> /data/backups/test.txt
    echo "actually done"
    exit 0 
}

start_mysql &
./entrypoint.sh --ignore-db-dir=lost+found
```

Comment: In the workflow you describe, in the `initContainer:`, the database isn't running yet, and you can't run a `mysql` command.  Can you start the database normally (using a StatefulSet, without an init container) and then load the data using a separate Job?

Comment: The workflow is.   CI deploys mysql deployment, init container started, sql dumps restored, main mysql deployment start with data all ready restored -> kubernetes pvc snapshot created.     i cant load it normally using a statefulset as i need to time when the snapshot is created based on when the data has restored. As the kubectl apply volumesnapshot will be run straight after the pod is in a "ready" state.   If this happens too soon the snapshot will just be a blank mysql.

Comment: also, the db isnt running, which is why i run the entrypoint.sh. the probnlem is this just stops everything when its done.  if i exec into the pod in a seperate shell, i can then run the mysql commands fine, but i need to be able to do this all from one shell, if that makes sense

Comment: what's the image of init-container you are using?

Comment: the image is mysql5.7

Answer (score 0):

you can start mysql sleeping in the background before mysqld. Would this work for you?

```
start_mysql {
    sleep 30
    mysql -u root -ppassword < /data/backups/backup.sql
    mysql -u root -ppassword < /sql-files/sql-files.sql
}

start_mysql &
./entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: hI I TRIED this ```start_mysql () {
    sleep 30
    #mysql -u root -ppassword < /data/backups/backup.sql
    #mysql -u root -ppassword < /sql-files/sql-files.sql
    echo "hi"
    sleep 30
    echo "done"
}

start_mysql &
./entrypoint.sh --ignore-db-dir=lost+found ```.  and it still starts it in the forground

Comment: ok, managed to get this working, and it restores and init container exits,  but when mounting that disk to a new pod, only has 1gb database size instead of 60gb? ..its like its not saved it to the disk

Comment: but you have commented lines `#mysql -u root -ppassword`. Was mysql executing?